# Redshift vs Oracle NUMBER datatype difference

Tags: oracle, amazon-redshift, type-conversion

I'm migrating from Oracle to Redshift. I have a column that is NUMBER(38,18) in Oracle and Numeric(38,18) in Redshift. If I have a value like 1200.0000, Oracle ignores the zeros after decimal places but redshift keeps the same representation. Is there a reason behind this difference? The output is going to be consumed by further EMR/Hive/Spark processing, I want to be careful and understand the difference. Please note that if there is non zero value after the decimal point, Oracle keeps them and this difference comes only for zero values after decimal point.

Comment: Are you using the same SQL client for both DBMS? If they are different, my bet is that one displays numbers differently then the other.

Comment: For NUMBER (NUMERIC) data type, 1200 = 1200.0000. So why do you think this is a problem (even if the databases choose to store the numbers in different formats)?

Comment: Empty fractions are not significant.  This leads me to believe that internal storage for numbers in Redshift might be character with on the fly conversion to float.  In any case, the reason is immaterial.  Other than the fact that if you want to display 18 zeroes after the number, you have to cast it to character in Oracle.